# declaration of ‘operator()’ as non-function

Tags: c++, templates

I am struggling to fix and understand this simple code reported as erroneous by the compiler which is supposed to define the call operator for `Klass`:

```
template<typename T>
class Klass{
    T operator(){ return T; }
};
```

g++ 7.3 reports:

```
a.cpp:3:26: error: declaration of ‘operator()’ as non-function
  T operator(){ return T; }
                          ^
a.cpp:3:26: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
```

What is wrong?

Comment: .`operator()()`

Comment: `T operator()(){ return T; }` But you then have another problem with `return T`, which is a type, not a value.

Comment: The form of declaring an `operator()` is `operator()(arg_types)`.   For example, if you want to call `object(2)`, `operator()` needs to be `T operator()(int x)`.

Comment: In the marked duplicate, look for "function call operator".   There are plenty of unrelated operators described.